# How was jquery $ selector defined before querySelector wasn't available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I've been searching all over the web, e.g. [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-vs-raw-javascript-1-dom-forms/), about how is jquery `$` function defined actually. That is how can the same functionality of jquery selector be achieved with plain javascript?

Everywhere it is said that jquery uses `document.querySelectorAll()`. That is `$` might be defined as follows:

```
function $(mystring) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(mystring);
}
```

Thats a good explanation. But my question is what did jquery use when `querySelectorAll` wasn't there in browsers? Without querySelector how is it possible to select elements like we do in css? E.g. `.container .row { ... }` in css selects every element with class `row` which is inside an element with `container` class. But in pure javascript we had only `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementsByClassName`.

The only option I see jquery would do is either use regex or pass the `mystring` to various conditions, e.g. checking whether the first character is `#` or `.`, whether there is `blankspace`, `>`, `~` keyword in `mystring` and then use `Node.childNodes` accordingly to return the proper element.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.12-stable/external/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to find the history of this project, but jQuery was built on the Sizzle engine. https://sizzlejs.com/

Comment: *Everything* in jQuery is done with plain JavaScript. DOM selection existed long before jQuery, irrespective of CSS style selectors being used.

Comment: Here is the original version of Jquery source, you can inspect.  https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.0.js   document.getElementByID / Tag, already existed, for classes I think it did filtering.  I beleive Sizzle JS, came later as they extracted the selector engine out.

Comment: ...and there are multiple standards-based JavaScript selector engines around that are implemented entirely without `querySelector`. How they parse the selector is up to them. They can use regex only, they can go without, or they can use regex for specific parts.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments state jQuery was built on the [Sizzle JS](https://sizzlejs.com/) engine which has a complex selector algorithm.

You can see this in use in jQuery 1 here:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js

Search for `Expr = Sizzle.selectors = {`

Even now jQuery simply uses Sizzle, however Sizzle has become more complex to take into account the use of `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: On line `113` there is _`matchExpr`_ which seems to be the modern `$` function. And it seems to heavily rely upon regex.

Comment: I think Sizzle came from JQuery, they extracted the selector engine. And then made that into Sizzle.  The version of JQuery you have shown is not the original..

Comment: @user31782 That's within the sizzle framework which is included as part of the jQuery framework.

Answer (score 0):

The important part of @Curt's link is at the bottom. It sets up the jQuery and $ object on the browser window, sets up an array for dependency injection, and creates the initial jQuery function.

It also insures that there is no conflict with other libraries that also us the $. It then sets both the jQuery and the $ on the window to the jQuery that is on the window. This exposes the library as it is returned in the last line.

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

The bottom of the file.

```
// Register as a named AMD module, since jQuery can be concatenated with other
// files that may use define, but not via a proper concatenation script that
// understands anonymous AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust
// way to register. Lowercase jquery is used because AMD module names are
// derived from file names, and jQuery is normally delivered in a lowercase
// file name. Do this after creating the global so that if an AMD module wants
// to call noConflict to hide this version of jQuery, it will work.

// Note that for maximum portability, libraries that are not jQuery should
// declare themselves as anonymous modules, and avoid setting a global if an
// AMD loader is present. jQuery is a special case. For more information, see
// https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Updating-existing-libraries#wiki-anon

if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function() {
        return jQuery;
    });
}




var
    // Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
    _jQuery = window.jQuery,

    // Map over the $ in case of overwrite
    _$ = window.$;

jQuery.noConflict = function( deep ) {
    if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
        window.$ = _$;
    }

    if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
        window.jQuery = _jQuery;
    }

    return jQuery;
};

// Expose jQuery and $ identifiers, even in
// AMD (#7102#comment:10, https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/557)
// and CommonJS for browser emulators (#13566)
if ( typeof noGlobal === strundefined ) {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
}




return jQuery;
```